# facebook share link "facebook URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed."

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

When I share a link from my site, it cannot detect thumbnail, title and description of the page...

I use facebook linter to identify the problem it gave me this error:
"facebook URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed."

this is the linter url:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.almadenahnews.com%2Fnewss%2Fnews.php%3Fc%3D509%26id%3D141802

this problem appeared only recently..
If anyone know how to solve it, please help me

Comment: I don't see the same error message that you do, but you're missing the og:url tag

Answer (score 4):

You should use Facebook User ID as `fb:admins` property (not the ID [#126788814107574](http://graph.facebook.com/126788814107574?metadata=true) of Application which you currently use).

This is confirmed by OpenGraph debugger error message:

> Object at URL 'http://www.almadenahnews.com/newss/news.php?c=509&id=141802' of type 'website' is invalid **because the given value '126788814107574' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.**

You also required (probably) to use `fb:app_id` property. See the [older docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) (in new documentation it's not stated anywhere that this is requirement but some things will just not work, comment moderation for example).

Comment: Thanks. I offered the bounty on behalf of [Anto](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1229959/anto-augustine) on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313676/facebook-share-link-facebook-url-requested-a-http-redirect-but-it-could-not-be) but I haven't had any feedback from him, or this question asker,   so I can't confirm this works but it looks plausible - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have put `126788814107574` as `fb:admins`, but if you look here,

http://graph.facebook.com/126788814107574

This clearly shows that `126788814107574` is an id of an app.

Instead of putting app_id, put your own profile id( or the profile id of admin,if its different )

This should solve the problem.

Also, app_id should be placed as

`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="<your_app_id>" />`

Comment: +1 thanks, and thanks for the meta property example. Juicy Scripter said most of that first though so I'm going to award him the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when i first converted my website from http to https. The solution is to manually rename 'http' to 'https' wherever you used so.